# Twig - "for" syntax with 3 operands, what does it mean

Tags: php, for-loop, templates, twig

I found a piece of legacy code with something like this:

```
{% for key, name, values in tag %}
...
...
{% endfor %}
```

*(This belongs to Twig 1, and now we are migrating to Twig 3.)*

So the "for" is extracting 3 values out of "tag" on each loop? I did not see this kind of construction anywhere in the documentation.

Is this ok? Someone help me understand this and can provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the third parameter `values` just gets ignored during the compilation, this is true for either `twig 1.X` as `twig 3.X`. It's safe to say that you can just omit the `values` parameter as it does not affect the template/output in any way

template

```html
{% for key, name, values in tag %}
{% endfor %}
```

compiled source for twig 1.42.0

```php
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable(($context["tag"] ?? $this->getContext($context, "tag")));
foreach ($context['_seq'] as $context["key"] => $context["name"]) {
}
```

compiled source for twig 3.3.2

```php
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable((isset($context["tag"]) || array_key_exists("tag", $context) ? $context["tag"] : (function () { throw new RuntimeError('Variable "tag" does not exist.', 1, $this->source); })()));
foreach ($context['_seq'] as $context["key"] => $context["name"]) {
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response and the nice explanation